# Answer aglomerate, group of possible solutions for a frequent question

Tags: discussion, support, duplicates

Is there a better way to answer the "upgraded and my 'random graphics maker string here' driver stopped working" (or any other derivatives of hardware category as long as its frequent)?

I have seen that some of you answer your own questions with known information, can a big post with some of the all solutions be created where people asking the same information over and over again be redirected to?

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you give some example? It's going to be difficult giving some sort of general answer to a range of hardware.

Comment: Like [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-card-supported-by-ubuntu). Every single "is my card supported" question can be redirected there. I just don't know if that is the best way of doing it or if there are some other suggestions.